# Rearrange the unique key column value sequentially

Tags: c#, oracle

In a database we have a table like

[image]

Here sequence is unique key and it basically displays the position of the row in UI. Now I need the change the position of the C2 to C1 by changing the C2 sequence to 1 and C1 sequence to 2. Same way I can rearrange the sequence and I am able to rearrange the sequence for the list in memory.

As I said earlier sequence is unique key in database (I am using oracle database) so when I try to commit the bulk update query it is showing unique key constrain error. I have some solution listed below.

**Solution 1**

Disable the unique key constrains and update the sequence and then enable the unique key for the table.

**Solution 2:**

1. Update the sequence of C2 to Max (sequence) +1.
2. Update the C1 sequence to 2
3. Update the C2 sequence to 1. This way we can avoid the unique key conflict.

**Example:**

We have to move C2 to C1 position so we will update

1. C2 => Max(Sequence)+1 => 5+1 =>6
2. C1=> 2
3. C2=>1

**Solution 3**

1. Update the sequence of C2 to -1
2. Update the sequence of C1 to -2
3. Rest all sequence should also modify to C2 to -3
4. C4 o -4

And then commit the change and again update all the sequence to (sequence)*(-1)
Again commit the changes.

**Solution 4**

We can also delete the both row from database and add it again with a rearranged sequence.

These are the four  solutions I have but all the three is not suitable for performance prospective. Please suggest me the most efficient way to solve this problem. I am using C# and oracle

Comment: Performance can only be measured, not really inferred from this. Number of rows, additional data etc etc affect it. But at least I wouldn't go deleting rows or changing constraints ever for this. And 3 doesn't need all rows updated. In the end 2 and 3 are exactly the same, just done a bit differently. So you really have one solution.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes. solution 2 and 3 are almost same just implementation is different. Actually all the solution i have listed here is not suitable. I am searching for some stander solution if any.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the wrong approach to update the unique key value on existing rows. Do it vice versa and update the rest of columns. e.g.

```
merge into yourtab f
using (-- exchange values of seq 1 and 2
       select 1 seq, 'C2' code, '1.2' name
         from dual
       union all
       select 2, 'C1', '1.1'
         from dual) src
on (f.seq = src.seq)
when matched then
  update set code = src.code, name = src.name;
```

btw I don't understand why you need to update seq to reorder the list in UI, why not simply reorder by `order by` clause?

Comment: No due to the business rules I can not update other columns. Update should only be in sequence column. We have drag and drop features in UI when we drag C2 and put it C1 position then C2 sequence should update and UI will display